# applying JQuery UI on dynamicllay created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing a web application using ASP.NET (VS2012,C#). I want to use JQuery UI draggable and resizable. They work fine on static objects (i.e. objects initially present in my HTML), but how can I apply these nice effects on elements created dynamically using javascript?

here is how I add my dynamic elements using JS:

```
var id =
    x[4] +
    "^" +
    x[0] +
    "^" +
    x[3] +
    "^" +
    x[2] +
    "^" +
    x[3] +
    "^" +
    x[5] +
    "^";

var eventdiv =
    "<div class='dragresize' id='" +
    id +
    "' onfocus='X()' onclick='ShowEditBox(this.id,event)' style='width:50%; cursor:hand; cursor:pointer; background-color:" +
    x[3] +
    "; border-style:solid; border-color:white; border-width:1px; height:60%'>";

if (x[0] != "")
    eventdiv += x[0];
else
    eventdiv += "(No title)";

eventdiv += "</div>";

document
    .getElementById('<%=tblWeek.ClientID %>')
    .getElementsByTagName("tr")[j + 1]
    .getElementsByTagName("td")[1 + i]
    .childNodes[0].innerHTML += eventdiv;

$(".dragresize").on("load", function () {
    alert('a');
    $(this).draggable();
    alert('c');
});
```

but the code in `$(".dragresize").on("load", function () {` is never run, what is going wrong here?

thanks in advance

Comment: would you show one example that how you apply JQuery UI on static element? I just wanna be the same page.

Comment: jQuery UI doesn't handle any delegation method (AFAIK), then you need to initialize plugin on dynamic elements once they are added to the DOM

Comment: Interesting, I was expecting some js code. You initialize your element in HTML, by giving class name?

Comment: Thanks A. Wollf, it was exactly what I was guessing, but how can I do so? can you please show me an example? for instance I make a div like this: <div class='dragresize' style='width: 50; height: 50; background-color:blue;/>, then add this div to another div (dynamically using JS), I will have several objects with class dragresize, I want all of them to be draggable/resizable, how is it possible?

Comment: Yes Jerry, in fact I'm giving my dynamically created objects a single class name (here dragresize) and then use:                                 $(function () {
                                    $(".dragresize").draggable();
                                    $(".dragresize").resizable();
                                });
is it correct?

Comment: @Ali_dotNet How do you add your elements dynamically? If you add your HTML elements (in this case, `dragresize` elements) with js, you can apply the JQuery UI code AFTER you add your elements.

Comment: @Ken I've updated my post, please take a look

Comment: @Ali_dotNet I'm assuming you get `alert('a')` and `alert('c')`?

Comment: @ken no, I don't get these alerts! and it is exactly the problem

Comment: @Ali_dotNet do the elements at least get added?

Comment: @ken yes everything is working correctly except JQuery UI functions

Comment: @Ali_dotNet check the development console for JQuery UI errors. And instead of the `.on()` function, I'd recommend `.ready()`

Comment: @ken how can I use .ready here?

Comment: @Ali_dotNet `$(".dragresize").ready(function(){ ... }`